# Android Sleep/Wait/Delay function

Tags: android, delay, sleep, thread-sleep

first of all, I'm a beginner to android world so please apologize me if it is stupid question..

I'm trying to do following:

1. Enable Mobile Data
2. Wait for 10 seconds
3. a. check if Mobile got IP address (data connected sucessfully)
   b. if Not connected,Disable Data
   c. Go to step 1

And these steps 1 to 3 are getting executed in For loop for User Given number of retries.

Now my problem is: I'm stuck at step No. 2.
 I'm unable to make `waitfor(int seconds)` function. I tried using Runnable PostDelayed method but it is not giving me required output.

```
for(retry = UserChoice; retry > 0 && !isDataAvailable ; retry -- ){
     enableInternet()
     delay(10)
     isDataAvailable = GetInternetAvailibility()
     if(!isDataAvailable){ 
         disableInternet()
     }
}
```

I tried to put `isDataAvailable = GetInternetAvailibility()` statement in `postDelayed` of handler but it is causing `enableInternet()` `disableInternet()` to execute at the same time while `isDataAvailable = GetInternetAvailibility()` gets executed after delay.

I can see from logs, that `enableInternet()` executes for `UserChoice` number of times without any delay.

Thread.sleep(10000) just freezes the UI for 10 seconds... How do I achieve this?

EDIT : Let me clear :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     // Perform action on click
    for(i=0; i<3; i++ ){
        System.out.println("Before..");
        delay(5);
        System.out.println("after..");
    }
}

public void delay(int seconds){
    milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                  final Handler handler = new Handler();
                  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           System.out.println("XXX");                 //add your code here
                       }
                  }, milliseconds);
             }
      });
}
```

Now whenever I click button I can see in logs that System.out prints message as:
Before
after
Before
after
Before
after
XXX
XXX
XXX

But I want:
Before
XXX
After.
Before
XXX
After.
Before
XXX
After.

Comment: Well if sleep() freezes your UI, your code seems to run on the "main" thread. Try running the code on a different thread.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try this:

```
public void check() {
    isDataAvailable = GetInternetAvailibility()
    if (!isDataAvailable) {
        disableInternet();
        enableInternet();
        if (retry > 0) {
            retry--;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    check();
                }
            }, 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code can be used in different ways. I've used it to change to stories after in my app similar to instagram. ThankYou

Answer (score 4):

This way may help you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code.Hope that it will help

```
int i = 0;
int j = 3;

method() {
    if (i < j) {
        System.out.println("Before..");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("XXXXXX");

                i++;
                System.out.println("after");
                method();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, thanks for the exact code. But I must give credit to viput as he came with the same logic first.. But thanks for this.. Well explained brother!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to put isDataAvailable = GetInternetAvailibility() statement
>   in postDelayed of handler but it is causing enableInternet()
>   disableInternet() to execute at the same time while isDataAvailable =
>   GetInternetAvailibility() gets executed after delay.

Put the if statement and disableInternet() in the postDelayed. enableInternet will get called, 10 seconds later it will check to see if the internet is available, if not it will disableInternet.

Comment: I tried that too.. but because of for loop, enableInternet() causes to execute say 5 times simulteniously. and then postDelayd statements come into picture when for loop has finishied its processing.